# Удаление элемента из RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть список который устанавливается в recyclerView. Как можно из него удалить  элемент?
Bот код адаптера:

```
public class RecyclerViewPizzasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewPizzasAdapter.PizzasViewHolder> {
    private int numbersItem;

    public RecyclerViewPizzasAdapter(int k) {
        numbersItem = k;
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PizzasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListIttem = R.layout.adapter_backet;

        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view = inflator.inflate(layoutIdForListIttem, parent, false);

        PizzasViewHolder viewHolder = new PizzasViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PizzasViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return numbersItem;
    }

    class PizzasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nameText;
        TextView countText;
        Button plus;
        Button minus;

        public PizzasViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textok1);
            countText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textok2);
            plus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            minus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(position));
                    ArrayList<String> Pizzas = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza1");
                    if (MainActivity.calzone.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza2");
                    if (MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza3");
                    if (MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza4");
                    if (MainActivity.mexican.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza5");

                    Log.i(TAG, "Button was clicked for list item " + position);
                    boolean b = true;
                    int i = 0;
                    while (b) {
                        i++;
                        String j = "pizza" + i;
                        if (j.equals(Pizzas.get(position))) {

                            b = false;

                            if (i == 1) {
                                int y = MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount();
                                MainActivity.pepperoni.setCount(y + 1);
                                Log.i(TAG, "+++++++++++++++++");
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }

                            if (i == 2) {
                                int y = MainActivity.calzone.getCount();
                                MainActivity.calzone.setCount(y + 1);
                                Log.i(TAG, "--------------");
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }

                            if (i == 3) {
                                int y = MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount();
                                MainActivity.quattrostagioni.setCount(y + 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }

                            if (i == 4) {
                                int y = MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount();
                                MainActivity.quattroformaggi.setCount(y + 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }

                            if (i == 5) {
                                int y = MainActivity.mexican.getCount();
                                MainActivity.mexican.setCount(y + 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(position));
                    ArrayList<String> Pizzas = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza1");
                    if (MainActivity.calzone.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza2");
                    if (MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza3");
                    if (MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza4");
                    if (MainActivity.mexican.getCount() != 0)
                        Pizzas.add("pizza5");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Button was clicked for list item " + position);
                    boolean b = true;
                    int i = 0;
                    while (b) {
                        i++;
                        String j = "pizza" + i;
                        if (j.equals(Pizzas.get(position))) {
                            b = false;
                            if (i == 1) {
                                int y = MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount();
                                MainActivity.pepperoni.setCount(y - 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }
                            if (i == 2) {
                                int y = MainActivity.calzone.getCount();
                                MainActivity.calzone.setCount(y - 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }
                            if (i == 3) {
                                int y = MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount();
                                MainActivity.quattrostagioni.setCount(y - 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }
                            if (i == 4) {
                                int y = MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount();
                                MainActivity.quattroformaggi.setCount(y - 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }
                            if (i == 5) {
                                int y = MainActivity.mexican.getCount();
                                MainActivity.mexican.setCount(y - 1);
                                BasketPage.onButton();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        void bind(int name) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(name) + "эээээээ");
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount()));
            ArrayList<String> Pizzas = new ArrayList<>();
            if (MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() != 0)
                Pizzas.add("Пепперони " + MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() + " шт.");
            if (MainActivity.calzone.getCount() != 0)
                Pizzas.add("Кальцоне " + MainActivity.calzone.getCount() + " шт.");
            if (MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() != 0)
                Pizzas.add("Четыре сезона " + MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() + " шт.");
            if (MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() != 0)
                Pizzas.add("Четыре сыра " + MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() + " шт.");
            if (MainActivity.mexican.getCount() != 0)
                Pizzas.add("Мексиканская " + MainActivity.mexican.getCount() + " шт.");
            nameText.setText(Pizzas.get(name));
        }
    }
}
```

и вот код активности:

```
public class BasketPage extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    public ScrollView scroller;
    public String name;
    public String phoneNumber;
    public String street;
    public String home;
    public String porch;
    public String level;
    public String apprt;
    public String comment;
    public boolean b;
    public static boolean chng = false;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static RecyclerViewPizzasAdapter adapteR;

    WorkBD workBD;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public void culculateFprice() {
        TextView FinalBuy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buyText);
        int Pprice = MainActivity.pepperoni.getFinalPrice();
        int Cprice = MainActivity.calzone.getFinalPrice();
        int QCprice = MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getFinalPrice();
        int QFprice = MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getFinalPrice();
        int Mprice = MainActivity.mexican.getFinalPrice();
        int FinalPrice = Pprice + Cprice + QCprice + QFprice + Mprice;
        FinalBuy.setText("Стоимось вашего заказа: " + FinalPrice + " руб.");
    }

    private int calculateAdapter() {
        int k = -1;
        if (MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() != 0)
            k++;
        if (MainActivity.calzone.getCount() != 0)
            k++;
        if (MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() != 0)
            k++;
        if (MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() != 0)
            k++;
        if (MainActivity.mexican.getCount() != 0)
            k++;
        if (k == -1)
            return -1;
        else
            return k + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bascket_page);
        mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        int CountAdapter = calculateAdapter();
        culculateFprice();
        workBD = new WorkBD(this);
        scroller = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        scroller.setOnTouchListener(this);
        if (CountAdapter != -1) {
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            adapteR = new RecyclerViewPizzasAdapter(CountAdapter);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapteR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (chng) {
            culculateFprice();
            chng = false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void onButton() {
        adapteR.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chng = true;
    }

    public void finish_check(View v) {
        b = true;
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorview);
        EditText namik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText phonik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        EditText streetik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.street);
        EditText homeik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.home);
        EditText porchik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.porch);
        EditText levelik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.level);
        EditText apprtik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.room);
        EditText commentic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);

        name = namik.getText().toString();
        t.setText("");

        if (name.equals("")) {
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        phoneNumber = phonik.getText().toString();

        if (phoneNumber.equals("")) {
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        street = streetik.getText().toString();

        if (street.equals("")) {
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        home = homeik.getText().toString();

        if (home.equals("")) {
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        porch = porchik.getText().toString();

        if (porch.equals("")) {
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        level = levelik.getText().toString();

        if (porch.equals("")) {
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        apprt = apprtik.getText().toString();

        if (apprt.equals("")) {
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        comment = commentic.getText().toString();

        String address = "Улица: " + street + ", Дом:  " + home + ". Номер подъезда: " + porch + ". Этаж: " + level + ". Номер квартиры: " + apprt;

        if (b) {
            SQLiteDatabase database = workBD.getReadableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_NAME, name);
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_ADDRESS, address);
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA1, MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA2, MainActivity.calzone.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA3, MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA4, MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA5, MainActivity.mexican.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_COMMENT, comment);
            database.insert(WorkBD.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно что бы когда количество элементов в элементе становилось равно 0 элемент из писка удалялся из RecyclerView.

Comment: MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() - вот так не надо передавать данные между активити, в один прекрасный момент они будут просто утрачены, так как система не гарантирует сохранение активити не на переднем плане. Передавайте через Intent или , если работаете с базой данных, читайте и пишите в базу напрямую, там, где это требуется (в каждой активити)

Comment: Насчет удаления, у вас в принципе неправильно сделана структура данных и проще, наверное, сделать, как надо, чем придумывать костыли, спасая то, что есть. Список чего отображает этот адаптер? Я так понимаю, в каждом айтеме есть несколько элементов (количество заказанных пиц), которые и надо динамически менять, а что в других айтемах этого списка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас неправильное взаимодействие с вашим адаптером. Я тут вам набросал пример адаптера.

```
    public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<YourModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ExampleAdapterListener listener;

    public ExampleAdapter(ExampleAdapterListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_list_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void updateAdapter(List<YourModel> list){
        this.items.clear();
        this.items.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteItemByPosition(int position){
        items.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteItem(YourModel model){
        items.remove(model);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView propertyOneText;
        private TextView propertyTwoText;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            propertyOneText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.property_one_text);
            propertyTwoText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.property_two_text);
        }

            void bind(final YourModel model, final ExampleAdapterListener listener){
                propertyOneText.setText(model.getPropertyOne());
                propertyTwoText.setText(model.getPropertTwo());

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        listener.onClick(model);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    interface ExampleAdapterListener {

        void onClick(YourModel model);
    }
```

Есть несколько вещей которые вы должны понимать про адаптер.

- Адаптер не должен знать никакой логики. В нем не должно происходить никаких просчетов. Все что он должен делать это получить на вход готовый список данных и отобразить их.
- В адаптере не должны обрабатываться клики. Адаптер должен сообщить сущности в которой он находится (в вашем случае Activity) только то, что на него кликнули и может быть передать модель или отдельные данные которые нужны для обработки клика. Не больше. А уже эта сущность должна решить, что с этим кликом сделать.
- Адаптер не должен сам в себя добавлять или удалять что-то. Все ваши данные для адаптера должны хранится в сущности которая отвечает за логику ( Presenter, ViewModel и т.п.), там должно происходить вычисление тех элементов которые должны отображаться в адаптере, а в сам адаптер должен просто передаться готовый список.

То что написали вы, как уже упомянули в комментариях лучше выбросить и переписать с 0! Потому что чем дальше вы будете пытаться спасти это, тем больше будет у вас проблем.